# What value we get when we subtract name of two labels and store it in a variable

Tags: assembly, masm, x86-16

What do we get when we subtract two labels in following manner:

```
L1 LABEL WORD
some code here....... 
L2 LABEL WORD
some code here....... 
ANS EQU L2-L1
```

here what will be the value of ANS.

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: You get the distance between them.

Comment: @RossRidge : they are using MASM. Their previous question and this one seem related to understanding the MS-DOS source code.

Answer (score 0):

Label addresses are relocatable and operations on them are restricted to addition and subtraction of constants. You can add a label address (relocatable value) to a constant but you cannot subtract a relocatable value from a constant. You also cannot add two relocatable values together.

In brief, it just cannot be done.

Comment: You can take a delta between two labels (subtract one from the other) if they're in the same section. The result is a scalar numeric value, in NASM terms. Label arithmetic like that allows to divide or shift label deltas, which is not allowed with labels that are relocateable (non-scalar) values.